# issue with ajax call on success

Tags: jquery

have the following implementation

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Member/SaveMember",
data: $('form').serialize(),
success: refreshGrid()
```

how come the refreshGrid() method is being called first prior to calling the ajax call of /Member/SaveMember  ?  I thought the "success" will only be called after successfully calling the server method.

any helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting up the ajax call with the result of calling your refreshGrid, not with refreshGrid as a reference. Remove the parenthesis to indicate that you do not want to call your method, but instead pass the method.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Member/SaveMember",
data: $('form').serialize(),
success: refreshGrid
});
```

If you want to set up the call with new parameters you wrap it in a new function

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Member/SaveMember",
data: $('form').serialize(),
success: function() {
    refreshGrid(dataParameter);
}
});
```

Comment: what about if i want to pass a value in the refreshGrid(somevalue)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `refreshGrid` only, without the parenthesis (when you use the parenthesis, you're calling the function, and attributing the result of the call to the `success` field).